# Getting Value from DropDownList to partial view using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm a novice in javascript, and a junior developper in OOP.

After many attempts and many google search I dind't make it to solve it.

I have a DropDownList and a Partial View. I  want to give the selected value to the partial view controller. It works when I write the value directly in, but it doesn't if i try to catch the DropDownList value. For the moment the value returned is always empty.

Model

```
public partial class Clients
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Adresse1 { get; set; }
    public string Adresse2 { get; set; }
    public string CP { get; set; }
    public string Ville { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateModification { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["oas"], new { @id = "ClientID" })

<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#ClientID').change(function () {
            //var pid = $("#id").val();//$(this).data('id');
            $('#result').load('@Url.Action("filter")',
                { id: $("#id").val() } //replacing $("#id").val() by "3" makes it work, but i of course don't a constant value here 
            );
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
public class OnePageController : Controller
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });
        var clts = (
            from c in db.Clients
            select c).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < clts.Length; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = clts[i].Nom,
                Value = clts[i].ClientID.ToString(),
                Selected = (clts[i].ClientID == 1)
            });
        }
        ViewData["oas"] = list;
        return View(/*db.Clients.ToList()*/);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Filter(string id)
    {
        var contact = from c in db.Contacts
                      where c.ClientID.ToString() == id
                      select c;
        return PartialView(contact);
    }
}
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated, also i don't know how to debug javasript, i use the developper tools in my when browser to try to catch the values, but i don't really track the changes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change a bit your script:

```
$(function () {
    // You select the element with id = ClientID
    var clientEle = $('#ClientID');

    // You register an event handler for the change of the selected value
    clientEle.change(function () {

        // clientEle.val() would return the selected value
        $('#result').load('@Url.Action("filter")',{ id: clientEle.val() });
    });
});
```

Regarding how you should debug JavaScript I would suggest to write the following keyword a few lines before you want to start the debugging:

```
debugger;
```

Then open developer tools and refresh your page. When JavaScript engine hits the debugger would stop it's execution and from this moment you could examine you code line by line.

For a thorough understanding in how you could debug JavaScript, you could start by checking the following links

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp